# Storing repeated Complex Calculations and serving through tastypie api

Tags: python, django, mongodb, caching, tastypie

I have a Django app which uses tastypie for apis.A python module does complex financial calculations when i hit the url and fetches only the required data for particular user.For the calcualtions some data are fetched from postgress and others from mongodb.

I dont want the calculations to be done when i hit the url it should be done once in 3 min and stored in-memory.WHen i hit url.It should fetch data which are available for the current user rather then fetching all the data.

show me a way on how to do it!I dont know where to look at exactly!
any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Make database models for cached data.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

#### 2. Make a manage.py command that does calculations and stores it to model from 1.

`project/calcucaltion_app/management/commands/calculate_data.py`

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from calculation_app.models import my_model

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = "No arguments needed"
    help = "This script calculates financial data and caches it"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # TODO code here
```

Remember to put empty `__init__.py` in `management` and `commands` folders. After this you can call you script with `./manage.py calculate_data` and the script will have access to django ORM. See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) for more information.

#### 3. Make a cron job that fires every 3 minutes and calls the command from 2.

Run `crontab -e` on your linux server and add:

```
*/3 * * * * /path/to/django/manage.py calculate_data
```

If you have set up a `virtualenv` you might need to make adjustments.

#### 4. Make a tastypie model that handles fetching data from the model in 1.

[Tastypie docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

Comment: awesome answer!! any link to go about with the step 2.